# can i work with multiple el's ( div's,ul or any element ) ia a single view/model in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I know this may sound dumb to most of you, but i'm in the beginning of understanding backbone.js. All i mean to say is that can we use more than 1 el/element ( whether it's div,ul or any element) in a view? 
More specifically saying when in a view/model we define el like this:
el: '#some_id'
can i have more el to work with in a model/view and how can we access each of them? 
right now with only 1 el, we use this to point to that specific el, but how to do if we can work with multiple el?
hope you guyz get what i'm trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way might be to use a single container element; you can access the child elements using `this.$("childelement")`.

You could also add more elements to your view class, or create composite views ([Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/lib/backbone.marionette.js) has some examples of composite patterns).  One of the nice things about Backbone is that it's *very* minimalist, in that it forces very few constraints on how you structure the site.  You can really extend/modify it any way you like.

The main uses of `View.el` are:

1. Wiring up events.  The view's `events` object applies listeners against the `el` container.
2. `View.remove` removes `el` from the DOM.
3. Basic helper methods `this.$el` and `this.$("selector")` are basic helper methods for accessing the DOM

These are all methods that you can easily override, or create your own implementations of.

Answer (score 0):

First, models don't know anything about el's.

Second, a view instance can only be attached to one el.  It can manipulate elements inside that one (`this.$("#child")`).  It can manipulate elements outside itself, although that is considered bad style.  Also, you can have multiple instances of that view, each connected to it's own el.

I hope that helps.